# bootstrap datepicker highlighting incorrect date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using bootstrap datepicker on my application (http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

I have a number of modals which can be loaded and each modal will have an datepicker inputfield (myDate)

When I click on the datepicker input field the first time no date is highlighted as expected.  When I select a date and then click off the input field and then click in it again the date that was selected is highlighted as expected.

When I click the next datepicker input there is no date in the input field value but the previous date selected was getting highlighted in blue.  I have fixed this issue with the code below (in the show) event which gets triggered when the selector is displayed.

```
$('#myDate').datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    endDate: "0d",
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
}).on('show', function (ev) {
    var dateValue = $('#myDate').val();
    if (dateValue === '') {
        $('.day.active').removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $('#myDate').datepicker('update', dateValue);
    }
});
```

So if the date value is empty then the blue active class is removed.  If the date input field has a value then it is set to that value.  The problem I am having though is that when it has a value - if the user uses the arrows to try and move to prev or next month then the 'show' event gets fired which then inadvertently sets the date back to the date that was in the input field and and so the user cannot traverse back and forward to select different dates.

I was trying to have a click handler on the 'prev' and 'next' class but that di not work as expected.

Anyone have any ideas on how to handle this?

Comment: Provide a working example that demonstrates the problem

Comment: @Dekel - fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/LcqM7/611/

Comment: if you run that with the console open you will see the show event displayed when you click on the input box (I want that behaviour).  However I want to prevent the message from being displayed if you use the arrow to traverse the months

Comment: Your current question in your comment is not even close to your original question. Which of them you want? :)

Comment: @Dekel - sorry I can write a new question if required.  I would prefer the question in the comment to be answered - if that is answered I will be able to use the logic to write some code to answer my original question :)

Comment: @Dekel - new question for reference - I will close out this question if required - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40364286/prevent-show-event-from-firing-when-on-datepicker