# prevent show event from firing when on datepicker

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I have a bootstrap datepicker.  I want the show event to be fired when the input box is first clicked.  However I don't want the event to be fired if the user is traversing through the months with the prev and next arrows.

Is this possible?

```
$('#sandbox-container input').datepicker({
    autoclose: true
});

$('#sandbox-container input').on('show', function(e){
    console.log('show event');
});
```

If you run the fiddle you will see the message get logged when you first click the input field (I want that behavior).  however you will also see that message displayed if you use the prev and next arrows.

JS Fiddler is here - http://jsfiddle.net/LcqM7/611/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to check if the `show` already "run" in the current "state".

```
$('#sandbox-container input')
    .on('show', function(e){
        if (! $(this).data('showrun')) {
            console.log('show event');
            $(this).data('showrun', true);
        }
    })
    .on('hide', function(e){
      $(this).data('showrun', false);
    })
    .on('changeMonth', function(e){
        console.log('change month event');
    });
```

And a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/k6b3yepb/

Comment: perfect this is exactly what I needed - Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit grim but you can leverage the `hide` event to unbind the `show` then reattach it using jqueries `one`.

http://jsfiddle.net/5dhkumko/

```
$('#sandbox-container input').datepicker({
    autoclose: true
});

$('#sandbox-container input').one('show', showMethod);

$('#sandbox-container input').on('hide', function(e) {
    $('#sandbox-container input').off('show', showMethod).one('show', showMethod);
});

function showMethod() {
    console.log('show event');
}
```